# React navigation with router go back button change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

react noob here. I have this mainpage with header, footer, and navigation bar where clicking on each nav link would show different component by changing the state.

I'm trying to implement `react-router-dom`, and I am having problem when I use `go back` button to my previous component/link. For example, I would see `comp2` and then `comp3` in order and press `go back` button to see `comp2` while at `comp3`, but no component shows up. Since I'm using state `activeTab` to render component I want, it seems like `go back` button would not call `setTab` when going back to previous. Is there a way to implement router so that I could freely `go back` / `go forward` rendering component I want without changing the way I implemented nav bar?

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Comp1 from "./Comp1";
import Comp2 from "./Comp2";
import Comp3 from "./Comp3";

function App() {
  const [activeTab, setTab] = useState(0);

  const TABS = {
    0: <Route path="/comp1" render={() => <Comp1 />} />,
    1: <Route path="/comp2" render={() => <Comp2 />} />,
    2: <Route path="/comp3" render={() => <Comp3 />} />
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Navbar setTab={setTab}></Navbar>
        {TABS[activeTab]}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
        <NavItem>
          <Link to="/comp1" onClick={() => props.setTab(0)}>
            Comp1
          </Link>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <Link to="/comp2" onClick={() => props.setTab(1)}>
            Comp2
          </Link>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <Link to="/comp3" onClick={() => props.setTab(2)}>
            Comp3
          </Link>
        </NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

Here is recreated example in CodeSandbox.io - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-snyder-ipyfn?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route is working as expected. But its how your component state is handled.

I have cleaned up your code. Router logic and component routing doesn't usually need state. the browser URL decides the component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-murdock-lt2j3?file=/src/App.js:380-598

You need to use switch case to handle routes correctly so that the first path match is considered.

```
<Switch>
   <Route path={menus.COMP1} render={() => <Comp1 />} />
   <Route path={menus.COMP2} render={() => <Comp2 />} />
   <Route path={menus.COMP3} render={() => <Comp3 />} />
</Switch>
```

Navbar can be state free:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
        <NavItem>
          <Link to="/comp1">Comp1</Link>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <Link to="/comp2">Comp2</Link>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <Link to="/comp3">Comp3</Link>
        </NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the back and forward buttons in the browser doesn’t update the application state as we would expect, it's essentially clearing out your state.

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Take a look at the use of the hooks here to see how they handle browser back and forward while still updating the component being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Router . it allows you to navigate the same with respect to URL and render the component.

I have updated your code to demonstrate the same into sandbox.
Please have a look.
https://codesandbox.io/s/little-tdd-bddu5?file=/src/App.js

Note: App.js and NavBar.js updated.